# How to raise a click event when user clicks on a main menu sub item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app with a FILE menu bar with the following menu items:

1. Open
2. **Recents**
3. Save
4. Exit

The Recents menu item gets populated with the most recent open directories

Recent:
   - ~\Documents
   - ~\Pictures

Any pointers / suggestion, what event I should subscribe to when a user clicks on one of the sub items within the **Recents** menu item?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MenuItem` class has a `Click` event.

**XAML:**

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
        <MenuItem x:Name="recents" Header="Recents">
            <MenuItem Header="Documents" Click="MenuItem_Click_1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Pictures" />
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

**Code:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MenuItem mi = new MenuItem() { Header = "test" };
    mi.Click += MenuItem_Click_1;
    recents.Items.Add(mi);
}

private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("clicked!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The looks of it show you want to have a menu with sub menus attached to it. The best way to do this in WPF is with menus with menu items inside of them which can then have buttons or more menu items.

The menus will automatically expand and show the other items inside of it, but if you would like a button click event that all you have to do is subscribe to the event handler, or double click on the button in the designer.

Comment: "To everyone who disliked this guys post, at least tell him why... He can't change unless he is told what he did wrong." - I back this too. But SO does asks you to read the *How to Ask* section before posting.

Comment: @Nobody True, I just feel bad, this person was probably stumped and maybe was searching the wrong places so he came here for help.

Comment: @Enigmativity Why did you remove my note to him about making sure his questions are clear and not already answered. I think he would benefit from seeing it and learning from it. Either way it is your decision.

Comment: @SeanMitchell - Don't put those kinds of messages in your answer - you should put them as comments on his question.

Comment: @Enigmativity I would, if I had 50 reputation. LOL